# Reinstall windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I just bought a new computer with a single hard disk with windows 10 installed on it.

I also bought a SSD. I want to swap the hard disk with the SSD to have windows 10 installed on the SSD.

The problem is : The computer have only 1 sata port. So I can connect only one disk at the same time.

How to proceed?

Comment: Do you want to reinstall Windows, or clone your old drive onto the new one?

Comment: I do not care. I just want to avoid license key problem

Comment: Then just install it on the new drive, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your Win10 key is persisted in `BIOS` - they all are since Windows 8.
You don't need to know it at all.
So the only problem you can encounter is that you might need a Windows 10 ISO/bootable device.

You can proceed so with **Windows 10 Creation Tool:**

https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/software-download/windows10

You can also use it for pushing big updates if they won't show up in your `Windows Update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reinstall Windows 10 using Media Creation Tool on new SSD and find the old Windows license key using Produkey to use it on new PC.

- [Download Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- [Download Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html#DownloadLinks)

Comment: The user shouldn't need to retrieve his license key, as it should be embedded in the BIOS.